# JQuery What is core.js (in jQuery 3.3.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just downloaded the latest version of jQuery via `npm install jquery` and it includes three uncompressed files namely:

```
dist/core.js
dist/jquery.js
dist/jquery.slim.js
```

**I'm wondering what the core.js file is** and couldn't find anything documented about it.  A google search on **core.js** and **jquery core.js** don't return relevant answers.

Also, I don't see any core.min.js.  So what is it?  Would I ever use it?

NOTE: It uses define() which requires an AMD loader (see https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#definition
) so it can't just be included straight into an html file.

One jQuery CDN is at https://code.jquery.com, but it doesn't include core.js (from what I saw).

Looking at the code it only defines a small number of functions some of which are:

```
extend, each, map, slice, first, last, eq, end
```

It looks like these are **also** defined in jquery.js and jquery.slim.js.

The jQuery documentation for **core** at https://api.jquery.com/category/core/ doesn't match what is in the core.js file.

Comment: Not sure why it is in a dist but core is mostly just methods used throughout the whole library

Comment: [Manipulation: Properly detect HTML elements with single-character names](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 2):

> core.js is responsible for defining the jQuery **namespace**, as well as
>   the **prototype** for jQuery objects. -  [How jQuery Works - An Introduction](https://benmccormick.org/2015/06/08/how-jquery-works-an-introduction)

This below may also be quite useful or at least help you get a better understanding, but to be honest the quote above i would argue is sufficient enough knowledge on the core.js file.

> It’s no longer maintained with newer versions, but a few years ago Rob
>   Flaherty created an annotated version of jQuery 1.6’s source.

[jQuery v1.6 Annotated Source Docs](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/)

[Core.js Annotated Source](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/01-core.html)